# Get type of arguments with one predefind argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

In c++ i want to get the type of the arguments of a function.
The issue is i don't want to get the type for all of the arguments only the ones after the first one

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncTraits : FuncTraits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct FuncTraits<R(C::*)(Args...) const> : FuncTraits<void(*)(Args...)> {};

template <typename... Args> struct FuncTraits<void(*)(Args...)> {
    using ArgCount = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>;
    using ArgsType = std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>;
};
```

In this example it gets the type for all of the arguments, but i want something more like this

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncTraits : FuncTraits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct FuncTraits<R(C::*)(int, Args...) const> : FuncTraits<void(*)(int unused, Args...)> {};

template <typename... Args> struct FuncTraits<void(*)(int unused, Args...)> {
    using ArgCount = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>;
    using ArgsType = std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>;
};
```

Yet this fails complete to compile.
How do i achieve something like this?

Comment: You should just need to add another template parameter like `typename T` and then you would have `FuncTraits<void(*)(T unused, Args...)`

Comment: Please include the full error message and all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another template type to the base overload of `FuncTraits`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct foo
{
    float operator ()(int a, char b, unsigned int c) const { return 0; }
};

template <typename T>
struct FuncTraits : FuncTraits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct FuncTraits<R(C::*)(Args...) const> : FuncTraits<void(*)(Args...)> {};

template <typename Arg, typename... Args> struct FuncTraits<void(*)(Arg, Args...)> {
    using ArgCount = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>;
    using ArgsType = std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>;
};

int main()
{
    using FooTraits = FuncTraits<foo>;
    std::cout << FooTraits::ArgCount() << '\n'; \\ prints '2'
    std::cout << typeid(FooTraits::ArgsType).name() << '\n'; \\ prints 'class std::tuple<char,unsigned int>'
}
```